# Is casting a pointer to intptr_t, doing arithmetic on it and then casting back, defined behavior?

Tags: c, gcc, c11

Let's say I want to move a void* pointer by 4 bytes. Are the following equivalent:

A:

```
void* new_address(void* in_ptr) {
    intptr_t tmp = (intptr_t)in_ptr;
    intptr_t new_address = tmp + 4;
    return (void*)new_address;
}
```

B:

```
void* new_address(void* in_ptr) {
    char* tmp = (char*)in_ptr;
    char* new_address = tmp + 4;
    return (void*)new_address;
}
```

Are both defined behavior? Is one more popular/accepted convention? Any other reason to use one over the other?.
Let's only consider 64bit systems. If intptr_t is not available we can use int64_t instead.

The context is a custom memory allocator which needs to move the pointer before allocating new block of memory to a specific address (for alignment purposes). We don't know what object the resulting pointer is going to point to yet but we know we need to move it to a specific location which in the examples above is 4 bytes.

Comment: I prefer the second one since it doesn't require casts.  Casts are over used and frequently evil.  In terms of perfectly defined behaviour, I think you are on thin ice.   Your original pointer, when unpacked from the void *, may no longer align properly for instance.

Comment: What happened when you tested them?

Comment: mevets, let's assume we take care to point to real objects in memory. 
Martin James, both work (compiled with gcc) but just because it works now on a specific system with a specific compiler doesn't make it future proof.

Comment: I'm not sure of the relevance of mentioning 64-bit systems or `int64_t`. Let's just assume `intptr_t` is available.

Comment: The hard coded `4` is future-proof? If the size is known, why not work with the specific type and use the usual pointer arithmetic?

Comment: Does `new_address` point within the same object as `pnt`? `Are both defined behavior?` Will you access the pointer, or are you just making arithmetic on it? Do you ask if accessing the resulting pointer is defined, or just if the conversion is defined? Does `in_ptr` is a valid pointer?

Comment: @WeatherVane because we don't know the specific type is going to point to yet. I've added some context to the question. 4 is hard coded to avoid logic which is not relevant to the question.

Comment: The C standard does not require the conversion from `void *` to `intptr_t` and back again to be a sensible, byte-for-byte, monotonic conversion, so any expectations on the result following addition would be your own expectations, not sanctioned by the C standard.

Comment: But since you tagged [tag:gcc], you could probably assume the conversion to behave sensibly for GCC at least.

Comment: Regarding GCC: The documented implementation-defined behavior for [Arrays and pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation) says "When casting from pointer to integer and back again, the resulting pointer must reference the same object as the original pointer, otherwise the behavior is undefined. That is, one may not use integer arithmetic to avoid the undefined behavior of pointer arithmetic as proscribed in C99 and C11 6.5.6/8.".

Comment: @IanAbbott this seems to answer part of my question (doing arithmetic on intptr and casting back is UB). What about doing it via char*? Memory allocator is one case, another I can think of is reading a stream of bytes and interpreting them as various objects. Let's say we have a float, an int and some struct stored one after the other, can I do arithmetic on char*, then cast to void* then to the object time to read the objects? Is that defined behavior?

Comment: I think the rules that govern the _effective type_ of an object allow objects to be treated as arrays of character type, and vice versa as long as the objects are correctly aligned. If the object is embeded in a stream of bytes in an allocated object then it has no effective type other than a character type until it is accessed by an lvalue expression that does not have a character type, at which point it has the same effective type as the lvalue expression (i.e. the same type as the deferenced pointer type used to access it). C11 6.5/6-7 has the gory details.

Comment: This is kind of pointless to discuss without knowing where those pointers point at to begin with, before you turned them into void pointers.

Comment: @Lundin they point into big empty space of allocated memory (the result of malloc) and are used to point to the place where objects of various types are going to be stored in. The was nothing those pointers pointed to before.

Comment: Ok then you will have no concerns about alignment and pointer aliasing etc. Meaning both versions will work just fine on any known compiler.

Comment: @IanAbbott: The rules about Effective Types and aliasing were never written in a manner that unambiguously describes all corner cases, because *there has never been a consensus about how such corner cases should be handled*.  If the Standard had explicitly stated that support (or lack thereof) for many corner cases is a Quality of Implementation issue over which it waives jurisdiction, that would have focused attention on what constructs quality implementations for various purposes *should* support, rather than pretending that all constructs for which which support isn't mandated are "broken".

Answer (score 2):

[Michael Kerrisk](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/The_Linux_Programming_Interface) says on page 1415 that,

> The C standards make one exception to the rule that pointers of
> different types need not have the same representation: pointers of the
> types `char *` and `void *` are required to have the same internal
> representation.

All the C standard guarantees (7.18.1.4) is that you can convert `void*` values to `intptr_t` (or `uintptr_t`) and back again and end up with an equal value for the pointer.

The nuance is here that we cannot apply mathematical operations (including `==`) if `void*` is in use.

Comment: I don't think the C standard makes any such guarantee. Does he name an exact chapter?

Comment: @Lundin yes sir, he touches on it at various parts in the book.  However, the part is excerpted from Appendix C. You can search some words of the text in the book to pinpoint.

Comment: @Lundin, how about C17, paragraph 6.2.5/28: "a pointer to `void` shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a pointer to a character type."  A footnote goes on to add that "The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to imply interchangeability as arguments to functions,return values from functions, and members of unions."  Similar language appears in previous versions of the standard.

Comment: @snr, pointers to `void` *can* be compared for (in)equality.  In fact, that is very common in the form of `if (p == NULL)`, though it is not limited to comparisons with null pointer constants.  As far as I can tell, pointers to `void` can be operands of relational operators, too, subject to the same semantics as pointers to other types.  What you cannot do with pointers to `void` (or to any other incomplete type) is pointer + integer addition or pointer - pointer difference.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, that settles it. I couldn't remember reading it in the standard before.

Answer (score 2):

> Is casting a pointer to intptr_t [...] defined behavior?

Converting a pointer to any integer type is defined and the result is implementation defined, except when result can't be represented in integer type, then it's undefined behavior. See [C11 6.3.2.3p6](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p6).  But `intptr_t` has to be able to represent `void*` - the behavior is defined.

> , doing arithmetic on it and then casting back, defined behavior?

Any integer may be converted to any pointer type. The resulting pointer is implementation defined - there is no guarantee that adding 4 to `intptr_t` will increment the pointer value by `4`. See [C11 6.3.2.3p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5).

> Are both defined behavior?

Yes, however the result is implementation defined.

> Is one more popular/accepted convention?

Subjective: I say using `uintptr_t` is more popular then `intptr_t`. Converting a pointer to `uintptr_t` or to `char*` to do some arithmetic happens in some code, I can't say which is more popular.

> Any other reason to use one over the other?.

Not really, but I think go with `char*`.

When it comes to actually *accessing* the data behind the resulting pointer - it depends. If the resulting pointer points within the same object then you're fine (remember, conversion is implementation defined). If the resulting pointer does not point to the same object, I believe the best interpretation would be from reading [c2263 Clarifying Pointer Provenance v4 2.2.3Q5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2263.htm#q5.-must-provenance-information-be-tracked-via-casts-to-integer-types-and-integer-arithmetic) and I think that's: the current C11 standard does not clearly specify that, which would make the behavior not defined.

Because you tagged `gcc`, both code snippets should compile to equivalent code - I believe on all architectures pointers are converted 1:1 to `(u)intptr_t` on gcc. [Gcc docs implementation defined behavior 4.7 arrays and pointers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Arrays-and-pointers-implementation.html#Arrays-and-pointers-implementation) states `casting from pointer to integer and back again, the resulting pointer must reference the same object as the original pointer, otherwise the behavior is undefined` - so you're safe as long as the resulting pointer points to the same object.

> The context is a custom memory allocator

See implementations of `container_of` and `offsetof` macros. Do not hardcode `+ 4` in your code, and if you do, do not depend on alignment requirements on accessing the resulting pointers - remember to use `memcpy` to safely copy the context or handle alignment properly. Do not reinvent the wheel - when in doubt see other implementations like [glibc malloc.c](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L2822) or [newlib malloc.c](https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/mallocr.c#L1411) - they both calculate on `char*` in `mem2chunk` macro, but also happen to do calculations on `uintptr_t` integers.

Comment: However, `intptr_t` is *optional*.  it is not guaranteed that an implementation provides any integer type that satisfies the requirements for that type, and if not, `intptr_t` will not be defined.

Answer (score 2):

No 'strictly conforming program uses A. Using the result may be Undefined Behaviour as there is no requirement for addition against `intptr_t` to be reflected in a pointer value if that `intptr_` is converted back to a pointer.
It is both unspecified behaviour and implementation-defined.

If the optional type `intptr_t` is defined all you are guaranteed is that you can convert `void *` to `intptr_t` and then convert that value back to `void *` and the two values will compare equal (==).

The `strictly conforming` way to perform pointer arithmetic is B. B is guaranteed to work if and only if the pointer `int_ptr` is valid and for the largest enclosing object there are 3 or more bytes in that object beyond that value. It's 3 because it's valid to point to (but not dereference) to the address that is (logically) one byte beyond the end of an object.

Object includes a declared object (including array) or block of memory such as returned by `malloc()`.

All good practice is to prefer to write 'strictly conforming' programs where possible. So all good practice is to prefer B over A.

According to the standard the use of the pointer (as a pointer) may result in Undefined Behaviour because it may be (implementation defined) to be a trap representation.

A [strictly conforming program](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#4p5) is defined as "A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the language and library specified in this International Standard.3) It shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any minimum implementation limit.

There's some disagreement about whether the code offered for A is unspecified or implementation defined. The standard says both because implementation-defined behaviour is a sub-category of unspecified. However because the implementation may document it as a trap representation using the value may result in Undefined Behaviour.

But I hope that is swept aside by the fact that 'strictly conforming programs' don't depend on unspecified, undefined or implementation defined behaviour.
So good practice here is certainly B.

Consider a secure environment that encrypts pointer values to deliberately confound the de-referencing of arbitrary pointer values. In principle it could provide `intptr_t` and be conformant.

Though I still maintain that if A doesn't work then `intptr_t` being an optional type it would be better to not provide it. Whether it is defined is unspecified and implementation dependent. That's because no 'strictly conforming program' uses it and it has no practical use other than to manipulate a pointer as an arithmetic type in a way not supported by pointer arithmetic on a compatible pointer type `char *`. The snippet in A falls into that category.
To store a `void *` declare a `void *` or char[sizeof(void*)] or `malloc()` or similar. To overlay a `void *` over an arithmetic type, declare a `union` and benefit that the `union` will be aligned for a `void *`.
But according to the specification it is unspecified, implementation-defined no 'strictly conforming program' can rely on it and may result in Undefined Behaviour.

A very long winded way of saying the answer, here, is B.

Comment: I think there is some missing word in your answer and I have problems understanding it. "B is guaranteed to work if and only if the largest enclosing object...?". The pointer in my case points to empty memory and will be used to store various objects there. Is it defined if I do that with char*? (as long as I take care of alignment)

Comment: @PiotrLopusiewicz I've tied up the wording. A block of memory returned by `malloc()` is an object also. The pointer arithmetic is well defined (within that constraint). Notice that `malloc()` returns a value aligned to store any variable. In C11 we have `aligned_alloc()`. Unless you're allocating a mixed object you can usually avoid casting to `char*` and adding numbers of bytes. I'm guessing the 4 you're adding is `sizeof()` something like `int`. The `char* +4` stuff is rarely needed, but it is well defined. and does what you want.

Comment: It's not necessarily undefined behavior, but impl.defined behavior. 6.3.2.3/5. You only get UB in case of misalignment or invalid pointer formats. On most real-world systems, the code posted will work just fine.

Comment: @Lundin It's certainly undefined behaviour by the C definition of undefined behaviour "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements". The standard imposes no requirement regarding intptr_t arithmetic in terms of casting resultant back to `void *`.
I mention 'in Standard C' because yes, on most real-world platforms intptr_t arithmetic does amount to pointer arithmetic. There's certainly no point in this case. `char*` pointer is the way forward for the OP's purpose.

Comment: `The standard imposes no requirement regarding intptr_t arithmetic in terms of casting resultant back to void *` It does: [C11 6.3.2.3p5](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p5): `An integer may be converted to any pointer type`. `The standard imposes no requirement regarding intptr_t arithmetic in terms of casting resultant back to void *` but it does - it imposes that the result is implementation defined, thus implementation has to implement and document some behavior.

Comment: @Persixty, behavior that the standard specifies to be implementation-defined does not satisfy that definition.  The standard does impose requirements on such behavior: that it conform to the (required) documentation of the C implementation in which it is exercised.

Comment: Fair play. Unspecified non-portable behaviour and dereferencing the value may result in undefined behaviour. That's a fine distinction but technically correct. The best kind of correct.

Comment: The standard has three formal and well-defined terms: undefined behavior, unspecified behavior and implementation-defined behavior. See [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/q/277486). There's nothing called "unspecified non-portable behavior" in C.

Comment: But which choice is made is implementation defined. And there's no useful way to code for them. By C terms that's unspecified 'unspecified behavior where each implementation documents how the choice is made'. Note the word choice. Having a fixed list options is still unspecified - unspecified which.
But there's nothing wrong with unspeicifed, The order of contigunity of return values of malloc is unspecified. But we don't care. What phrase do you want for some that by way of being unspecified cannot be used in a portable way?

Comment: @Lundin. See also the footnote 'The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment.'. I struggle to think of anything less defined and less portable. I see the fine point that the value can be placed in a pointer. But using it is (of coursed) undefined.

Comment: @Lundin Don't forget it's unspecified (by the standard's terms) whether `intptr_t' is declared because it's optional and the implementation 'makes a choice' and so its use is not portable (to environments that make the choice to omit it). It is unspecified and is non-portable.

Comment: In this specific example. Undefined behavior = if converting the changed address back to a pointer results in misalignment or a pointer trap representation, a crash or similar. Unspecified behavior = the compiler has deterministic behavior for how it treats addresses on this given system, but it isn't documented anywhere. Implementation-defined = the compiler has deterministic behavior for addresses on this system and the alignment requirements, addressing etc of the CPU core are well-known and documented. Thus: it is implementation-defined behavior on all real-world computers.

Comment: @Lundin "unspecified behaviour where each implementation documents how the choice is made". Implementation defined behaviour is a sub-category of unspecified behaviour. If you're right I'm right call it unspecified. 
I agree 'real world' and the note  "The mapping functions for converting a pointer to an integer or an integer to a pointer are intended to
be consistent with the addressing structure of the execution environment" implies that A is intended to work. But it is non-portable.

Comment: @Lundin I'd say the specification should be harder and say if `intptr_t` is provided it *must* reflect the addressing structure (in the sense that A amounts to pointer arithmetic). That's because if it doesn't I know of no practical use for it.
But as it stands it is unspecified and doing it is (in principle) non-portable.

Comment: @Lundin I've worded round the debate because A is not 'strictly conforming', B is and show always be preferred (for this case).

Comment: @Persixty: Indeed, I fail to see much purpose to be served by allowing implementations define types `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` without having guarantee anything about their semantics beyond the fact that a round-tripped pointer compare equal to the original pointer.  The Standard allows for the possibility that a pointer just past the end of one object compares equal to a pointer to another object that immediately follows it, even though each object might only be accessible (without UB) using its own pointer.  Thus, a conforming but capricious implementation could decide...

Comment: ...that if `&y` happens to equal `(&x)+1`, that `int *p = (int*)((uintptr_t)&y)` would set `p` to `(&x)+1` if downstream code tries to access `*p` [thus causing such access to invoke UB] or `&y` if downstream code tries to access `p[-1]` [thus invoking UB in that case].  Of course, such issues could be fixed if the Standard made clear that in cases where parts of the Standard and an implementation's documentation would describe a behavior, but other parts say it's not required, the question of whether to behave usefully is a Quality of Implementation issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

Comment: Agreed. I still think the quality of the standard could be improved by making it explicitly implementation defined whether if `uintptr_t uip=(void*)p` then `v=uip+n` will convert to a pointer with value `ps=(char*)p+n` if `ps` that value is a valid pointer. And further for what values of `a`, if `ps` is valid pointer that if `v%a == 0` `ps` shall have alignment of `a`. It's clear (here and elsewhere) that's what developers want and even expect from `uintptr_t`. Note: Valid values of `a` may differ from those valid for `aligned_alloc()`.